# Do we need something in the Help Center in place of our scope?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I was looking around at the [LH Help Center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help) and I realized that it does not give helpful information at all.

In the [on-topic question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section all it says is

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Lifehacks Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created

It doesn't say anything about the on-topic questions. This page is almost useless.

Now I know that we are still hashing out the details about what is on-topic and what is off-topic, but right I think we need to put something in the Help Center.

Should we add something, even if it is small, that will help new users better understand what questions to ask?

Comment: The help center should summarize the scope. But we haven't settled on a scope yet (there are discussions on meta which don't reach a consensus and diverge from what is happening on the main site), so at this point I don't see anything useful to put in the help center.

Comment: What @gilles said. Staff and moderators (once appointed) can update the Help Center, but... nobody's sure what to put in there yet.